# Como faço para limpar um JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jpa, jtable

Estou usando o JPA para preencher minha tabela que se localiza num `Jframe`.

Através do JPA, faço uma seleção no meu banco para achar todos os nomes que possuam parte do nome que escrevi, por exemplo, se me entrada for "m", todas as pessoas com nome começando por "m" devem aparecer na minha lista, se alterar por "mi" só queles que tenham o nome que começa com essas duas letras aparece, e se a entrada for vazia, aparece todo os clientes na tabela.

Atê ai tudo certo, o problema e que não estou conseguindo limpar minha tabela para a próxima pesquisa, ele apenas substitui as linhas e o resto fica o resultado da pesquisa anterior, gostaria de saber como fazer para poder apagar a cada pesquisa.

```
package br.com.exemplo.telas;

import br.com.exemplo.conexao.JPAUtil;
import br.com.exemplo.entity.Cliente;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//biblioteca rs2xml.jar

/**
 *
 * @author costa
 */
public class TelaConsultar extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    int idtb;
    EntityManager conexao;

    /**
     * Creates new form TelaConsulta
     */
    public TelaConsultar() {
        initComponents();
        conexao = new JPAUtil().getEM();
        pesquisar();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tblClientes = new javax.swing.JTable();
        txtCliPes = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtConId = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnRemove = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setClosable(true);
        setIconifiable(true);
        setMaximizable(true);
        setTitle("Consulta");
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));

        tblClientes.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        tblClientes.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                tblClientesMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(tblClientes);

        txtCliPes.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtCliPesKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });

        txtConId.setEnabled(false);
        txtConId.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtConIdActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnRemove.setText("Excluir Cliente");
        btnRemove.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnRemoveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Edita Cliente");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(txtCliPes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 259, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                        .addComponent(txtConId, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 594, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                .addComponent(btnRemove)
                .addGap(221, 221, 221))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtCliPes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(txtConId, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 188, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnRemove)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(67, 67, 67))
        );

        setBounds(0, 0, 641, 480);
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    // O evento abaixo e do tipo "enquanto vou pesquisando"
    private void txtCliPesKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
        pesquisar();
    }                                     
     //Enveto que serar usado para setar os campos da tabela clicando com o mouse
    private void tblClientesMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        int setar = tblClientes.getSelectedRow();
        System.out.println(tblClientes.getModel().getValueAt(setar, 0).toString());
        idtb = Integer.parseInt(tblClientes.getModel().getValueAt(setar, 0).toString());
        //Abre o form TelaCliente

        /*try {
            int setar = tblClientes.getSelectedRow();
            String id = tblClientes.getModel().getValueAt(setar, 0).toString();
            TelaAterar tela = new TelaAterar();
            tela.setVisible(true);
            tela.setarCampos(id);
        TelaPrincipal desc = new TelaPrincipal();
        desc.desktop.add(tela);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }*/

    }                                        

    private void txtConIdActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void btnRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        int sair =JOptionPane.
                showConfirmDialog(null, "Tem certeza que deseja apagar?", "Atenção",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);  
        if (sair == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            deletar();

        }

    }                                         

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        TelaAterar tele = new TelaAterar();
        TelaPrincipal tela = new TelaPrincipal();
        tele.setVisible(true);
        tela.desktop.add(tele);

    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnRemove;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable tblClientes;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCliPes;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtConId;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    //Metodo para setar os campos do formulario com o conteudo da tabela
    private void pesquisar() {

        conexao.getTransaction().begin();


        //limpaTabela();
        String jpql = ("select c from Cliente c where c.nome like  :cNome");

        Query query = conexao.createQuery(jpql);
        query.setParameter("cNome", txtCliPes.getText() + "%");

        List<Cliente> cliente = query.getResultList();
        int i = 0;

        for (Cliente cli : cliente) {

            tblClientes.setValueAt(cli.getId(), i, 0);
            i++;
        }

        conexao.getTransaction().commit();

        //Usar a Biblioteca rs2xlm.jar para preencher a tabela
        //      tblClientes.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }



    private void deletar() {
       conexao.getTransaction().begin();

       Cliente cli =conexao.find(Cliente.class, idtb);
       conexao.remove(cli);

        conexao.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se estiver usando `DefaultTableModel` o comando abaixo já resolve:

```
((DefaultTableModel) suaTable.getModel()).setRowCount(0);
```

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setRowCount-int-), o método `setRowCount` define o número de linhas que o model padrão deverá ter, se o tamanho definido for menor que o tamanho atual de linhas, as linhas excedentes serão descartadas.

É só colocar logo no começo do seu método de pesquisa, substituindo `suaTable` pela variável correta do seu `JTable`.

---

Adaptando ao código de pesquisa, você também deve alterar a forma como vai adicionar os itens, pois o método acima irá zerar a lista de objetos do `DefaultTableModel`, e utilizar `setValueAt` irá estourar `ArrayOfBoundException`. Adicione novas linhas usando `addRow`:

```
private void pesquisar() {

    conexao.getTransaction().begin();


    //limpaTabela
    ((DefaultTableModel) suaTable.getModel()).setRowCount(0);

    String jpql = ("select c from Cliente c where c.nome like  :cNome");

    Query query = conexao.createQuery(jpql);
    query.setParameter("cNome", txtCliPes.getText() + "%");

    List<Cliente> cliente = query.getResultList();

    for (Cliente cli : cliente) {

        tblClientes.addRow(new Object[]{cli.getId()});
    }

    conexao.getTransaction().commit();

    //Usar a Biblioteca rs2xlm.jar para preencher a tabela
    //      tblClientes.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
```

Comment: Estou puxando a tabela direto do Jframe, e por isso não estou usando o DeafaultTableModel

Comment: @MiguelCosta então você criou um TableModel proprio?

Comment: Sim, basicamente criei um JFrame e puxei o Jtable da Paleta junto com os campos de textos e botoes como pode observar aqui.

 private javax.swing.JButton btnRemove;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable tblClientes;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCliPes;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtConId;

Comment: @MiguelCosta se você criou um TableModel proprio, então você é quem deve implementar essa remoção nele. No caso do Default, ele já possui o recurso pronto para que você possa fazer uso sem ter que se preocupar com implementação. No caso de personalizar, ai a responsabilidade do recurso é do programador.

Comment: Sim, mas essa implementação que não estou acertando fazer, por isso vim aqui descobrir algum modo que eu não tenha pensado para implementar

Comment: @MiguelCosta posta o código do seu  TableModel na pergunta. Ou tente simplesmente adicionar o trecho da resposta pra ver se funciona.

Comment: Postei a classe todaa agora

Comment: @MiguelCosta pelo código postado, você está usando o defaultTablelemodel sim, a solução da resposta vai servir. Basta colocar no início do método de pesquisa.

Comment: Eu ja tentei o código acima, deu esse erro: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Comment: @MiguelCosta se vive quer limpar e continuar usando o mesmo tablemodel, você não pode adicionar novos valores usando `setValueAt`, e sim `addRow`.

Comment: Agora estar funcionando normalmente, muito obrigado

Comment: @MiguelCosta que bom que funcionou. Fiz uma atualização, veja se você fez dessa forma, é a que tentei explicar no comentário anterior.

Comment: @Miguel alguma razão por ter desfeito o aceite? A resposta não lhe tinha atendido?